# How do you use autocomplete for thousands of entries?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, codeigniter, autocomplete

Is there a way to setup autocomplete in PHP/jQuery that can quickly run through thousands of rows in a database?

I have a job board where the user enters his/her college - and I want to offer autocomplete.  Problem is, there are 4,500 colleges in the united states and a  seems like an awful solution.

Is there a good way to both make the query fast, and return results only when there are less than 10 options available?

Thank you in advance,
Walker

Comment: Just use a LIMIT on the SQL query. I see no reason to display more than about 10 possible results. 4,500 rows isn't actually such a big number in database terms.

Comment: As Byron said, just limit the query results. 4500 is not much

Comment: I thought LIMIT was for specifying ranges in the database?  How does that apply to this problem (sorry for the novice question).

Comment: yup, the LIMIT just tells the database to return first **n** records. the rest is not taken into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Anax. You may want to look at a simple solution like the new [jQuery UI Autocomplete field](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Using the delay and minLength options, you could keep the script from querying the server until the user has entered say three characters, which would reduce the number of results.

PS. There is also a caching option which may be useful. You could cache the entire list client-side lessening the calls to the database.

Comment: + 1 The new jQuery UI Autocomplete is the best.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to use AJAX, given the number of records. Basically, you need to monitor keystrokes and call a PHP script, which in turn will fetch the relevant records from the database.

A good example would be the [dhtmlxCombo](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCombo/).

Comment: Is that smarter than querying all the results and storing them in an array?  Is querying the database each time a letter is pressed less intensive/ as quick?

Comment: I believe so. I have already implemented the jQuery combo box in a project and I'm pulling the results from a 10k+ records long table. I wouldn't dare to pull all the records and once and have the users download a huge html document.

Answer (score 2):

You could first ask for other qualifiers like 'desired region/state', 'specialty', etc. and then begin autocomplete after the user has entered 6 or more characters to filter-out more of the 4,500 colleges?

Comment: I up voted this because of future-proofing the concept of auto-complete. As your dataset expands you are going to want to take steps to tailor the suggestions to the user of the app. This is something we do via geo-location, user profile data, and search history.

Answer (score 0):

4500 is not too much, depending on your hardware / number of users / how often you *really* need it, you could keep the List in the memory ([MySQL Memory engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html) as example).
But, as already suggested, when only getting results when there are 3 letters+ you might not even have a problem at all.

Comment: except for the fact that probably more than half the students in the US, for example, attend colleges called 'University of [State Name]'

Comment: If there are a lot of results starting with the same name, logging & hardcoding some things might be a solution (if search is part of uni* return "University of " and only do a real search if there is some evaluable data, something like that) --- and, depending on how people are using the form, keeping the last results in memory might help as well (APC). Checking the logs if its useful per case again..

Answer (score 0):

Use this, http://devthought.com/wp-content/projects/jquery/textboxlist/Demo/